# Service in Angular not successfully returning variables

Tags: angularjs

So I wrote a service to perform the $http.get calls and return the necessary variables that I needed for the functionality of my template. The issue I'm having is even though I'm able to see and log the data on the server side, whenever I call my service and try to access the variables that it's supposed to return I just get 'undefined'.

My service is as follows:

```
function getResultsPage($http) {
        var fetchPage = function(pageNumber, filterType, searchVal) {
            var recordCount;
            var contactsPage = [];
            $http.get(
                    '/searchTotal?filterType=' + filterType + '&searchVal='
                            + searchVal).then(function(response) {
                recordCount = response.data;
                console.log("recordCount: " + recordCount);
            });
            $http.get(
                    '/search?filterType=' + filterType + '&searchVal='
                            + searchVal + "&pgNo=" + pageNumber).then(
                    function(response) {
                        response.data.forEach(function(contact) {
                            contactsPage.push(contact); // load search
                            // results into
                            // contactsPage
                        });
                    });
            return {
                recordCount : recordCount,
                contactsPage : contactsPage
            };
        }
        return {
            fetchPage : fetchPage
        };
    }
```

and my Controller:

```
function ContactsController($http, $filter, getResultsPage) {
    var self = this;

    // Begin lazy loading code
    self.filterType = 'LastName';
    self.contactsPage = [];
    self.recordCount = 0;
    self.usersPerPage = 15; // this should match however many results your
    // API puts on one page
    self.pagination = {
        current : 1
    };
    self.pageChanged = function(newPage, filterType, searchVal) {
        self.filterType = filterType;
        self.recordCount = getResultsPage.fetchPage(newPage, filterType,
                searchVal).recordCount;
        console.log("record count in js = " + self.recordCount);
        self.contactsPage = getResultsPage.fetchPage(newPage, filterType,
                searchVal).contactsPage;
        console.log("contactsPage in js = " + self.contactsPage);
    };

    self.pageChanged(1, 'LastName', 'a');
    // End lazy loading code
```

Here is a picture of the output from my log statements within the pageChanged function:

[image]

To clarify: I'm getting the 1822 contacts back from my query, but from my controller I can't get that number to bind to self.recordCount, and I can't get the returned array of contacts to successfully bind to self.contactsPage either. 
Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: Please do not [cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info): http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/322332

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the logs, the js console log (`console.log("record count in js = " + self.recordCount);`) is executed first since the service call is async. Try using a callback function which sets the variables when the service has returned.